req.cookies NEXTJS Middleware undefined on Production
this my next middleware :
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
const token = request.headers.get('token')
console.log(token)
if (!token || token == undefined) {
return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url))
}
}

export const config = {
matcher: \['/admin/:path\*'\]
}

this response from backend express :
  `res.cookie('token', response.token, { 
    maxAge: maxAges,
    httpOnly: false,
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    sameSite: 'none'
  })`

in local this methode is work. but if i try to deploy using https for frontend and backend this methode not working.

Hi, Did the below answer help.

Please see the comments and suggestions below.

res.cookie statement creates a cookie in the response object
In order to get this cookie saved in the browser, the corresponding request should have been invoked with credentials : “include”, if not, the cookie will be ignored by the browser.
const token = request.headers.get('token')
The above statement is to get the header token. However a cookie will not be available in it unless it has been set explicitly by code.
If there is a cookie successfully stored in the browser, as mentioned in step 2, then to send it back to the server, 
each request should be invoked with credentials : “include”, otherwise cookies will not be sent to the server.
if cookies are successfully sent to servers, then it can be read as below example
request.cookies.get('token)


